# Bootstrap3 Glyphicons not showing on Chrome Version 37.0.2062.103m

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

The icons are displayed as small squares in my Chrome, I'm version 37.0.2062.103.

Only can see 8 icons in the following page:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Anyone knows why?

Comment: I can see them all. (using same version)

Comment: Try to clear browser cache and try again

Comment: Clear cache doesn't work. Re-installation solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I found the cause is some google app I installed in chrome. Remove the apps solved my problem. I found this after a re-installation.

It turns out to be the app which forces Microsoft YaHei font.

Comment: what app? I have the same problem at times?

Comment: Not sure. I just deleted them all. You can delete one by one to check.

Comment: It turns out to be the app which forces Microsoft YaHei font.